# Overwrite instead of add for duplicate triplets when creating sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

In scipy, to create a sparse matrix from triple format data (row, col and data arrays), the default behavior is to sum the data values for all duplicates. Can I change this behavior to overwrite (or do nothing) instead?

For example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse

rows = [0, 0]
cols = [0, 0]
data = [1, 1]
S = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))
```

Here, `S.todense()` is equal to `matrix([[2]])` but I would wish it to be `matrix([[1]])`.

In the [documentation of sparse.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), it reads

> By default when converting to CSR or CSC format, duplicate (i,j)
>   entries will be summed together. This facilitates efficient
>   construction of finite element matrices and the like.

It appears from that formulation that there might be other options than the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen discussion on the scipy github about giving more control over this summing, but I don't know of any production changes.  As the docs indicate, there's a long standing tradition over summing the duplicates.

As created, the `coo` matrix does not sum; it just assigns your parameters to its attributes:

```
In [697]: S = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))
In [698]: S.data
Out[698]: array([1, 1])
In [699]: S.row
Out[699]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [700]: S.col
Out[700]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Converting to dense (or to csr/csc) does sum - but doesn't change `S` itself:

```
In [701]: S.A
Out[701]: array([[2]])
In [702]: S.data
Out[702]: array([1, 1])
```

You can performing the summing inplace with:

```
In [703]: S.sum_duplicates()
In [704]: S.data
Out[704]: array([2], dtype=int32)
```

I don't know of a way of either removing the duplicates or bypassing that action.  I may look up the relevant issue.

=================

`S.todok()` does an inplace sum (that is, changes `S`).  Looking at that code I see that it calls `self.sum_duplicates`.  The following replicates that without the sum:

```
In [727]: dok=sparse.dok_matrix((S.shape),dtype=S.dtype)
In [728]: dok.update(zip(zip(S.row,S.col),S.data))
In [729]: dok
Out[729]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [730]: print(dok)
  (0, 0)    1
In [731]: S
Out[731]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [732]: dok.A
Out[732]: array([[1]])
```

It's a dictionary update, so the final value is the last of the duplicates. I found elsewhere that `dok.update` is a pretty fast way of adding values to a sparse matrix.

`tocsr` inherently does the sum; `tolil` uses `tocsr`; so this `todok` approach may be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only values of 1:

```
S.sum_duplicates()
S.data[:]=1
```