# Pair-wise distance of points, with pair specified by incidence sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

In my code I have an array of point position and a sparse incidence matrix. For every non-zero ij-element of the matrix I want to calculate the distance between the i-point and j-point.

Currently I'm extracting the indices with the 'nonzero()', however this method sort the output indices, and this sorting is taking most of the execution time of my entire application.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import scipy.sparse

#number of points
n = 100000 


#point positions
pos = np.random.rand(n,3)

#building incidence matrix, defining the pair wise calculation
density = 1e-3
n_entries = int(n**2*density)
indx = np.random.randint(0,n, n_entries)
indy = np.random.randint(0,n, n_entries)

Pairs = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(n_entries) ,(indx,indy)) , (n,n))



#current method
ii,jj = Pairs.nonzero() #this part is slow

d = np.linalg.norm(pos[ii] - pos[jj], axis = 1)

distance_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d , (ii,jj)) , (n,n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modified answer

The main problem is that there are sometimes duplicates in `indx, indy`. For this reason, we cannot simply do:

```py
d2 = np.linalg.norm(pos[indx] - pos[indy], axis=1)
distance_matrix2 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d2, (indx, indy)), (n, n))
```

...because then the values at duplicated indices would be multiplied by the number of duplicates.

The original answer below was first deduplicating indices. But even with the faster `pd_unique2_idx`, the whole operation ends up to take more time than the original.

Instead, since you already calculated `Pairs` (which, if you noticed, also has the duplicate indices problem: `Pairs.max()` often gives more than 1.0), let us try to get indices of non-zero values without any sorting, just using what is in the structure.  Here is a way to do it, following the definition of `indptr` and `indices` [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```py
ii = Pairs.indices
jj = np.repeat(np.arange(len(Pairs.indptr) - 1), np.diff(Pairs.indptr))
```

What you get is the same indices as your own `ii, jj`, but ordered differently (column-major instead of row-major).

**Timing**

Just looking at the part that gets `ii, jj`:

```py
%timeit Pairs.nonzero()
# 1.27 s ± 5.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.repeat(np.arange(len(Pairs.indptr) - 1), np.diff(Pairs.indptr))
# 41.3 ms ± 49.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

In context:

```py
def orig(pos, Pairs, n):
    #current method
    ii, jj = Pairs.nonzero() #this part is slow
    d = np.linalg.norm(pos[ii] - pos[jj], axis=1)
    distance_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d, (ii, jj)), (n, n))
    return distance_matrix

def modified(pos, Pairs, n):
    # only change: these two lines:
    ii = Pairs.indices
    jj = np.repeat(np.arange(len(Pairs.indptr) - 1), np.diff(Pairs.indptr))
    # unchanged
    d = np.linalg.norm(pos[ii] - pos[jj], axis=1)
    distance_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d, (ii, jj)), (n, n))
    return distance_matrix
```

On your data (with `np.random.seed(0)` to start, for repeatable results):

```py
%timeit orig(pos, Pairs, n)
# 2.16 s ± 15.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit modified(pos, Pairs, n)
# 1.11 s ± 4.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Correctness**

```py
dm = orig(pos, Pairs, n)
dmod = modified(pos, Pairs, n)

np.all(np.c_[dm.nonzero()] == np.c_[dmod.nonzero()])
# True

i, j = dm.nonzero()
np.all(dm[i, j] == dmod[i, j])
# True
```

#### Original answer

You could calculate another list of distances in `indx, indy` order, then make a sparse matrix of that:

```py
d2 = np.linalg.norm(pos[indx] - pos[indy], axis=1)
distance_matrix2 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d2, (indx, indy)), (n, n))
```

However, comparison with your own distance matrix shows some rare but possible differences: they come from the case where you have repeated locations in `indx, indy` and the corresponding `Pairs.toarray()[indx, indy]` is the number of repeats. This stems from a well-known "feature" of `csc` and `csr` sparse matrices that duplicate elements are summed. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40727524/758174) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28680079/758174).

For example:

```py
>>> indx = np.array([0,1,0])
>>> indy = np.array([2,0,2])
>>> scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(3), (indx, indy))).toarray()
array([[0., 0., 2.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Unfortunately, the solution proposed by @hpaulj in the posts linked above using `todok()` do not work anymore with recent versions of scipy.

Using `np.unique()` is slow, as it sorts the values. `pd.unique()` is faster (no sort), but accepts only 1D arrays. Here is a way to do a 2D unique that is fast. Note that we need the indices of the unique rows, so that we can index `indx` and `indy`, but also the distance matrix if that was already calculated.

```py
def pd_unique2_idx(indx, indy):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[indx, indy])
    return np.nonzero(~df.duplicated().values)


# by contrast (slower on long sequences, because it sorts)
def np_unique2_idx(indx, indy):
    rc = np.vstack([indx, indy]).T.copy()
    dt = rc.dtype.descr * 2
    i = np.unique(rc.view(dt), return_index=True)[1]
    return i
```

On 1M elements for both `indx` and `indy`, I see:

- `pd_unique2_idx`: 52.1 ms ± 529 µs per loop
- `np_unique2_idx`: 972 ms ± 19.5 ms per loop

How to use this? Following your setup:

```py
i = pd_unique2_idx(indx, indy)
indx = indx[i]
indy = indy[i]
d2 = np.linalg.norm(pos[indx] - pos[indy], axis=1)
distance_matrix2 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((d2, (indx, indy)), (n, n))
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specified that Pair is given by the application, so in reality I don't really care about duplicates. However your index calculation with indices and indptr is what I was looking for. Thanks you.

Comment: Ah, cool. Glad it helped. @hpaulj's solution of using `.tocoo()` and then `.row` and `.col` is quite interesting too. However it is twice slower than calculating indices as done here using `numpy`. It would be nice to have a `csr.get_indices()` or something like that that does the same without having to hack our way  into it.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample arrays:

```
In [104]: Pairs = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(n_entries) ,(indx,indy)) , (n,n))
```

the time create the `csc` itself is not trivial:

```
In [105]: timeit Pairs = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(n_entries) ,(indx,indy)) , (
     ...: n,n))
1.08 s ± 44.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`nonzero` converts the matrix to `coo`, and then does a extra check for 0s:

```
def nonzero(self):
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask], A.col[nz_mask])
```

The `coo` conversion is relatively fast.  I don't think there's any sorting involved.

```
In [106]: timeit Pairs.tocoo()
221 ms ± 17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That extra masking does add time.

```
In [107]: timeit Pairs.nonzero()
1.86 s ± 37.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Since a freshly made `csc` will not have any explicit 0s, you could do something like:

```
M = Pairs.tocoo()
ii,jj = M.row, M.col
```

Creating the `coo` matrix directly is faster:

```
In [108]: timeit sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(n_entries) ,(indx,indy)) , (n,n))
158 ms ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This sets the `row` and `col` to `indx` and `indy` directly (or at most with a dtype change).  It's the `csc` creation that sorts the indices (lexically by row and then column), and does any duplicate summation.